# Is it possible to open a modal box up from a select2 box

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I am very very new to select2 and it's capabilities. What I need to do is have a button at the end of a select2 list which brings up a popup modal that then allows the user to add more information and details.

Is this possible?

This is what I currently have:

```
 $("#s2").select2({
    placeholder: "Select users",
    width: '100%',
    allowClear: !0,
    closeOnSelect: false,
    maximumSelectionLength: 2,
    ajax: ---> gets my data from  service
}).on('select2:select', function (e) {
    if ($(this).select2('data').length >= 2) {
        $(this).select2("close");
    }
});
```

Is there any way to open a modal from within the select2 list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#SELECT_ID').select2({
    ajax: {        
    },
   // other params
   ...
   //
          
}).on('select2:open', () => {
    $(".select2-results:not(:has(a))").append('<a href="#" style="padding: 6px;height: 20px;display: inline-table;" onclick="addNewItem()">ADD NEW</a>');
});

function addNewItem() {
  // Show modal with "Add form"    
}
```

After adding new item to DataBase just close modal and check dropdown in select2.

Comment: Thank you! Can that link be a button instead of a just a text link? Is it possible? Or is a select2 list limited to text only?

Comment: It will be displayed under the list of options. You can style it like a button using custom class and CSS. You can also change it to button in code and style it the same way.